# What does $ROOT mean in a Mac Terminal?

Tags: command-line

I received some command line instructions:

```
ROOT=`cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`
echo ROOT=$ROOT
...
```

It seems that this $ROOT stores the output of the three pipelined cmds. But what is $ROOT? Is it an environment variable? Is it a register? How should I call it? Can I have other variables like it? For example $APPLE? I hope to learn more about $ROOT :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROOT` is an environment variable, plain and simple. `$ROOT` is simply the expansion/evaluation of the `ROOT` environment variable.

For example:

```
xyzzy=plugh
echo xyzzy     # gives xyzzy
echo $xyzzy    # gives plugh
```

What the `ROOT` environment variable is *used* for may be important (or not) but the actual *naming* of it is not in doubt - it's an environment variable called `ROOT`.

Answer (score 1):

Root is an [environment variable](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html). Variables are expanded during execution, so when `echo` echoes $ROOT, it is expanded to the contents of the variable. In this case, the backquotes mean "execute command", so the output of `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3` is emitted. What is confusing about your example is that the `echo` command uses the variable name as text as well, perhaps this makes more sense:

```
ROOT=`cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`
echo The ROOT variable is: $ROOT
```